# LWC passing parameter into navigation state

Tags: lightning-web-components

When navigating between lwc's is it possible to pass values from the html to the state when the onclick event is used please. I'd like the c__propertyID to be retrieved from there so I'd like label to be something from my html. I know how to get them from the URL in the lwc but can't work out how to pass it in.

```
viewProperty() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: { componentName: 'c__ViewPropertyAura' },
             state: { c__propertyID: label}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you need

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url